# I want to create button, where the title of the button will change depending on conditions

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to create button, where the title of the button will change depending on conditions. the conditions are,
check if application is present in system:
if yes button title will be open
if no button will be install
if there is any update update ....
same like the playstore 'install' button.

Comment: You may explore along these lines. Have a method that will check the conditions & return the appropriate title for the button. Within the rendering, simply invoke the method. So, something like this: `const getBtnTitle = () => { if (condition1) return "Open"; if (condition2) return "Install"; ...};`. And when rendering: `<button ...>{getBtnTitle()}</button>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) on the official React documentation.